# Javascript: Call top-level window function from inside object

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>window.bark = function() {
      console.log('woof')
    }
    </script>
    <object role='img'
      data='https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg'
      onclick='window.bark()' />
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that the content inside the object tag has its own document context, but am wondering: is there any way to permit the object to call the function bound to the window?

Comment: Maybe `window.top.bark()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be impossible under your current implementation, and not because the `object`'s `window` is under a different global context. (In fact, that click event isn't even inside the `object`'s document. It's inside the top document, so scope wouldn't be a problem.)

It's because you can't effectively listen to clicks directly on an `object` element. The same would apply to an `iframe`, for example. Click events are triggered inside the element's document, not on the element itself.